# Yahoo pipes - compare item content from multiple feeds

Tags: rss, compare, yahoo-pipes

In yahoo pipes I have two rss feeds. 
Now I want to grab item content from second feed to compare it with item content in first feed.
Based on GUIDs. 
If it matches I want the items from first feed in my output.

Can someone help pls?

Thanks

Bane

Comment: Why use Yahoo Pipes for this?

Comment: because with yahoo pipes a can generate an RSS Link with the output

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with YQL Plugin query:

```
select * from rss where url='feed1' and guid in (select guid from rss where url='feed2')
```